# write IEnumerable<IEnumerable<Point>> to file

Tags: c#, io, ienumerable

I am having trouble figuring out how to write this collection out to file.  I have the following classes

```
public static class GeoPolyLines
{
    public static ObservableCollection<Connections> connections = new ObservableCollection<Connections>(); 
}

public class Connections
{
    public IEnumerable<IEnumerable<Point>> Points { get; set; }

    public Connections(Point p1, Point p2)
    {
        Points = new List<List<Point>>
         {
                new List<Point>
                {
                    p1, p2
                }
         };
    }

}
```

And then a bunch of things like this:

```
 GeoPolyLines.connections.Add(new Connections(new Point(GeoLocations.locations[0].Longitude, GeoLocations.locations[0].Latitude), new Point(GeoLocations.locations[1].Longitude, GeoLocations.locations[1].Latitude)));
```

So GeoPolyLines.connections will eventually have a bunch of different locations that I want to then write out to a .txt file to save and reload if I need to.  But I don't know how to do this.  I have something like this:

```
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(filename))
{
    var enumerator = GeoPolyLines.connections.GetEnumerator();

    while (enumerator.MoveNext())
    {

    }
    sw.Close();
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use serialization.

To write to file

```
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

File.WriteAllText(filename, serializer.Serialize(points));
```

and to read from file

```
var points = serializer.Deserialize<List<Point>>(File.ReadAllText(filename));
```

Comment: I am still a noobie but from what I read yesterday serialization doesn't work for static classes.  But will this work ?

Comment: @jimjohnjim `Connections` is not a static class. You can serialize `GeoPolyLines.connections` with a single line of code. `serializer.Serialize(GeoPolyLines.connection)`

Comment: I'm getting an error that it can't be serialized because it doesn't contain a parameterless constructor.

Comment: @jimjohnjim then add `public Connections(){}`